# Google Maps API v3 overlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been programming with Google Maps API since 3.6. I have been using `google.maps.GroundOverlay`. So what is the difference between this and `USGSOverlay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core difference is ,that [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay) is a part of Google Maps V3 API, but USGSOverlay is not.[USGSOverlay](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) is just illustrutation of [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView)'s implemenation, which you need add to your code , whenever you want to use it,but in GroundOverlay's case ,it is not neccessary. It is coming with Google Maps API's script. The other difference is, you can specify opacity of overlay in GroundOverlay's case, but you can't do that thing by USGSOverlay(you need to customize the code a little bit to achieve this).